# Less memory usage for simple calculations on big random arrays in C++

Tags: c++

For some molecular dynamic simulation I created some simple C++ code to create a random distribution of particles in 3D space:

```
double ** X = new double* [N]; 
    X[0] = new double[C];
    for(int i=0; i < C; i++)
        X[0][i] =  R_max  * (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;

double ** Y = new double* [N]; 
    Y[0] = new double[C];
    for(int i=0; i < C; i++)
        Y[0][i] =  R_max  * (double)rand() / RAND_MAX; 

double ** Z = new double* [N]; 
    Z[0] = new double[C];
    for(int i=0; i < C; i++)
        Z[0][i] =  R_max  * (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
```

After that step some particles have to be deleted dependent on some additional properties (for example the distance between particles) that also have to be calculated. Therefore I use simple loops:

```
for (int m=0; m<C; m++){
for(int l=0; l<m; l++){
    r_x[l][m] = X[0][m]-X[0][l]; 
    r_y[l][m] = Y[0][m]-Y[0][l];
    r_z[l][m] = Z[0][m]-Z[0][l];
    r[l][m]= sqrt(r_x[l][m]*r_x[l][m] +r_y[l][m]*r_y[l][m] + r_z[l][m]*r_z[l][m]);

    if(r[l][m] <= ...)...;
    }
}
```

In the last step the coordinates have to be stored in some file, I use fopen and again, some simple loops:

```
    FILE *file;
file=fopen("system.ini","w");
for(int i= 0; i< ...; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<...; j++){
    fprintf(file,"%lf %lf %lf\n",X[i][j],Y[i][j],Z[i][j]);
    }
}
```

That worked fine but now I have to scale up the systemsize by a factor of a few 1000 so my 16 GB memory is no longer sufficient enough to calculate the additional properties. Ofcourse professional simualtion software won't take more than a few 100 MB memory and a fraction of the computing time for the same calculations, how can I make this simple code a little bit more efficient?

Comment: `double ** X = new double* [N];` -- Why are you allocating `N` pointers when your code only uses the first one, i.e. `X[0] = new double[C];`?

Comment: Declare a class, say cParticle, with attributes for the location, and use a one dimensional vector of particles.

Comment: First, you should calculate if it is possible at all, what are you asking for. How many numbers do you need to store in memory?

Comment: Bascially, your code above is `struct XYZ { double x, y, z; };  std::vector<XYZ> data(C);` Because you allocate only one item in second dimension?

Comment: Are you even using r_x, r_y, r_z and r outside of the loop? Why do these have to be matrices at all?

Answer (score 0):

Do a google for "C++ Sparse Matrix" and you'll find a ton of implementations and discussions.

Geeks for Geeks talks about rolling your own. Boost has a class for it. Those were the most interesting links from the first page.

I think the key to this is understanding what a sparse matrix is. After that, the rest is pretty straightforward.